# Is it able to use Sony remote SDK on macOS 14 and Xcode 15

Tags: sony, sony-camera-api

I'm trying to build a small program with Sony remote sdk and A7RM4. When I try to use the demo app, it alerts me with "A connection operation timed out". Although I can get into to further menu, I can't do anything like change iso, white balance or release shutter. I'm using Xcode 15.1 and macOS 14.2.1.

```
RemoteSampleApp v1.11.00 running...

Remote SDK version: 1.11.00
Initialize Remote SDK...
Working directory: /Users/User
Remote SDK successfully initialized.

Enumerate connected camera devices...
Camera enumeration successful. 1 detected.

[1] ILCE-7RM4 (CFB5204EE962)

Connect to camera with input number...
input> 1

Connect to selected camera...
Create camera SDK camera callback object.
Release enumerated camera list.
<< TOP-MENU >>
What would you like to do? Enter the corresponding number.
(1) Connect (Remote Control Mode)
(2) Connect (Contents Transfer Mode)
(x) Exit
input> 1

Remote Control Mode
<< REMOTE-MENU >>
What would you like to do? Enter the corresponding number.
(s) Status display and camera switching 
(0) Disconnect and return to the top menu
(1) Shutter/Rec Operation Menu 
(2) Shooting Menu 
(3) Exposure/Color Menu 
(4) Focus Menu 
(5) Setup Menu 
(6) Other Menu 
input> 
[CAT: Connect   ] [DETAILS: A connection operation timed out]
ILCE-7RM4 (CFB5204EE962)
Please input '0' after Connect camera
```

I don't have another Mac device than the m2 Mac book pro I'm using now, so I check the SDK on Windows and it works well. Right now, Sony remote SDK haven't announced that they support macOS 14, so I just wondering if it is possible to use the SDK.